# Unable to select Target framework for XNA 4.0 games

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, xna-4.0

I have an XNA 4.0 project that I would like to be compiled with the .Net 4.0 Full profile, but it is set to Client profile by default. The *Target framework* combobox in the Application tab is grayed out.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled .Net 3.5, .Net 4.0 and Xna 4.0. What could be the problem? Our other development machines do not have this problem.

[image]

Comment: Are you able to create a fresh XNA project and reproduce the problem in that?

Comment: In a fresh XNA project it is perfectly reproduceable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a workaround:

In the `.csproj` file is an xml element called `TargetFrameworkProfile` which is set to `Client`. When I remove the word Client and thus empty the xml node, the project is built as a full .Net 4.0 assembly.

You can even upgrade the project to .NET 4.5 or higher by changing the `TargetFrameworkVersion` element. We use this to be able to use the Kinect One camera in XNA games.

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

Answer (score 0):

Where do you see that your project is set to the client framework? I created several XNA-projects but never got problems with this.

My Target framework box is disabled too.

If you're getting bugs, I think you've to search for another cause.

Greatings

Comment: When you add a reference it mentions "Filtered to: .Net Framework 4 Client Profile" on top. Also in the .csproj file TargetFrameworkProfile is set to Client. I don't get bugs, but it is annoying I can't use certain references such as the content manipulation pipeline functionality in XNA.

Comment: If you reference a .Net Framework 4 (full profile) assembly that uses something outside of the Client Profile (such as System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode) from within your XNA project, the build will fail with a ton of ambiguous error messages for every type you reference: `The type or namespace ... could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).` Updating as `Wouter` suggests fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Per Wouter's answer, here is the proper XML in the `.csproj` file:

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
<TargetFrameworkProfile></TargetFrameworkProfile>
```

Comment: Why is `<TargetFrameworkProfile></TargetFrameworkProfile>` necessary?

Comment: To demonstrate (per Wouter's answer) that it should *not* contain the text `Client`. It should be empty.