# XNA GameStudio 4.0, How to target full .NET framework (4.0)

Tags: xna

I need the ColorEditor in a WindowsGame, by default WindowsGames target the .Net 4 ClientProfile framework, but I need the full one.
Under Project Properties -> Application the field "Target Framework" is gray and I cant change it.

any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to select Target framework for XNA 4.0 games](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6522455/unable-to-select-target-framework-for-xna-4-0-games)

Answer (score 0):

I'm also using XNA 4.0 and there's no problem you described. Try to create a new project and check out the project properties.