# Dependency on Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0 - loading animated models to XNA 4.0

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

I used the [skinned model sample](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/skinned_model) from Microsoft to load my Blender model (.fbx) and play their animations. A import SkinnedModelWindows and SkinnedModelPipeline projects and I added them as a reference. But when I want to get skinning data (from SkinnedModelPipeline) I get this warning:

```
The referenced assembly "...\SkinnedModelPipeline.dll" could not be resolved because it has a dependency on "Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which is not in the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client". Please remove references to assemblies not in the targeted framework or consider retargeting your project.
```

and skinning data is still null:

```
SkinningData skinningData = model.Tag as SkinningData;

        if (skinningData == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException
                ("This model does not contain a SkinningData tag.");
```

from this I get the exception.

And ideas how to solve it?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your project needs to be built against the full version of the .NET Framework, rather than the Client Profile.  In the project properties in Visual Studio, there should be an option that lets you change the target framework on the Application tab.

Comment: In the SkinnedModelPipeline project it is set to: .Net Framework 4.0 - not to the client version. And in my base project (the application) I can't select the "Target framework" in properties. It is disabled. Output type is set to Windows Application.

Comment: @Darkry That issue is addressed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6522455/unable-to-select-target-framework-for-xna-4-0-games). Of course, your game shouldn't be referencing a pipeline extension in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Re-check the sample and look at which project is referencing which:

- Your game project should only reference `SkinnedModelWindows`
- Your content project should only reference `SkinnedModelPipeline`
- `SkinnedModelPipeline` references `SkinnedModelWindows`

All projects only need to target the .NET 4.0 client profile, *except* for `SkinnedModelPipeline`, which requires the full framework (because the content pipeline assemblies for building content require it).

Comment: All references are set exactly as you said. SkinnedModelPipeline is .NET Framework 4.0 (no client) version set and the other projects (my project and SkinedModelWindows) has disabled the Target framework option.

Comment: I have to change those grayd out tabs? I think it should go without changing it.

Comment: Note the link in my comment on Cole Campbell's answer, if you are having trouble with the disabled target framework option. ([Here it is again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6522455/unable-to-select-target-framework-for-xna-4-0-games).)